# Convert string to date with independent format

Tags: vb.net

Lets say I have this string with this date. "02-01-2015"

The string build like this: dd-MM-yyyy, which means this date is January 2 2015. I need to insert this string to my SQL database as a date. How do I tell the database that the first integer is the day and not the month and so on. This is what I've tried so far.

```
    Dim dateTime As String = "02-01-2015"
    Dim dt As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime)
    Dim format As String = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    Dim str As String = dt.ToString(format)

    MsgBox(str)
```

Now the real problem begins. I live in Denmark and my computers default system time format is different from the english time format. When I run this code on my pc with default time-format on my system i get the msg:

```
2015-02-01
```

But if I change my system time format to english, i get this msgbox:

```
2015-01-02
```

How do i make this independent of the system time format? Can I split up the string into year, month and day or is there someway to always use english timeformat when converting to date? I know this might seem like a simple problem to you, but it's been challenging me in a while now. Looking forward to your response!

Comment: If it is a date and the db column is date, pass a date and you wont have to tell it anything about the date.  The NET db Providers are well suited to handle NET Dates.  Dates dont have a format and you cannot force one on them.  Formats are just how they are diplayed to people. Thus, you see it differently depending on the active culture.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is if i parse this data to my database. I can mix up the dates if i run the program on a computer with a different active culture. I've just tried this and i get two different dates in my database. One says 2015-01-02 and another one says 2015-02-01 but they are converted from the same string with the same code, just using 2 different computer formats.

Comment: No. `Jan 2` in the UK is `Jan 2` in Demark and `Jan 2` in the US.  The problem you see is further upstream.  Provided the db column is Date, the source data is being parsed to the wrong culture as per your last question.  If the DB column type is string you may have shot yourself in the foot.

Comment: The DB column type is date.. I know jan 2 is the same in all 3 countries but this string: 02-01-2015 is converted via the same code to 2 different dates in my database. This row: 2015-02-01 and 2015-01-02. This has nothing to do with one country reading it one way and another reading it another way, since this error would apply to both dates and i should either get the correct format in both or the incorrect in both cases. I just need to tell the vb.net date which format the string is it. How do i do that.

Comment: As you can see then i tell the program to convert the date to a string again in this format. yyyy-MM-dd. When it returns 2015-02-01 then it this its the 2nd month (february). So there is a problem when i convert to datetime without a specific format. Then it assumes 02-01-2015 means feb 2nd 2015.

Comment: Strings are not dates, the layout/format **only** matters when displaying it to humans or parsing a date from a string.

Comment: I know a string doesnt have an actual attribute called format, but if i tell you to meet me at 2o'clock on 2015-03-01 then it's important for you to know what format i used to display the date as a string to know if i Mean march 1.  or january 3. Same applies when going back from string to date. I need to define  the specific format of the string to convert it to the correct formatless date the server understands

Comment: I think you're building the INSERT query using string concatenation. If you use parameters instead, then this problem will go away. (This is what Plutonix was getting at in the first comment)

Comment: You guys are probably right. Anyway i've posted my solution below if anyone has the same problem.

Comment: I missed a part of the question, but the error in your thinking is that `"02-01-2015"` has some universal fixed meaning.  It doesnt.  Nor is it a DateTime.  All that code proves along with the change from X to Y culture is that the same text different parse result depending on the culture.  If you started with a ***date***: `Dim dt = #01/02/2015#` the results would not vary,

Comment: I know 02-01-2015 doesn't have some universal fixed meaning, but when i convert from a string to a date, it has to assume some fixed format the string is in. In this case in denmark the default fixed meaning is mm-dd-yyyy where in america the default fixed meaning is dd-mm-yyyy so when i convert it to a date, then i need to specify which fixed meaning my exact string is in.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution:

```
 ' a date value in the string format specified:
        Dim xmlDate As String = "02-01-2015"

        ' create a DATE variable from that string in a known format:
        Dim newDate As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(xmlDate, "dd-MM-yyyy", Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        MsgBox(newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```